В случае использования одинакового алиаса дважды, на какой будут ссылаться последующие обращения?
Есть запрос, который дважды джойнит таблицу с одинаковым алиасом (но разными условиями). К какому из двух наборов данных будут обращаться последующие упоминания этого, одинакового для двух таблиц алиаса?
SELECT ...
  FROM table_1
  JOIN table_2 A ON ...
  JOIN table_3 A ON ...
  JOIN table_4 B ON A.col_1 = B.col_1

Простой проведенный мной эксперимент со следующим запросом:
  WITH
    test_1 AS (SELECT 1 AS col_1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS col_1 FROM dual)
  , test_2 AS (SELECT 2 AS col_1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS col_1 FROM dual)
  , test_3 AS (SELECT 1 AS col_1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS col_1 FROM dual)
  , test_4 AS (SELECT 1 AS col_1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS col_1 FROM dual)
SELECT *
  FROM test_1 b
  LEFT JOIN test_2 a ON a.col_1 = b.col_1
  LEFT JOIN test_3 a ON a.col_1 = b.col_1
  LEFT JOIN test_4 c ON a.col_1 = c.col_1;

Результат:



col_1
col_1
col_1
col_1




1
null
1
null


2
2
2
2



Намекает на то, что джойн таблицы test_4 происходит к первому упоминанию алиаса. При этом все чатботы уверены, что должен использоваться последний упомянутый алиас. Поэтому для обоснования багфикса потребуется высеченное в граните правило (может эксперимент не охвативает все возможные случаи поведения). Так как "по правилам" используется алиас, который использован дважды в Oracle?

В интернетах пишут, то это в общем-то баг, который был пофиксен в свежих версиях Оракла. Так то по-хорошему он должен ругаться на дупликат алиаса, и ругается в свежих версиях.

"По правилам", алиас должен быть уникальным. Как и названия столбцов. Да, оракл выведет это, однако этот вывод будет отдан на откуп внутреннему движку и результат может быть непредсказуем.

@SwaD мы имеем дело с легаси, и именно уникальные алиасы я сейчас раздаю. Но нужно понять на какой из уникальных алиасов мы хотим ссылаться в последующих джойнах.

Тут вам явно не расскажут, какая логика была заложена в sql запрос и какой результат ожидается

@SwaD мне нужно понять не какая логика заложена, а какая она по факту. Как ведет себя Оракл в таких ситуациях и почему.

Это баг древней версии Оракла. Не нужно полагаться на ошибку в ПО и выводить правила, по которым она работает. Этот баг был давно исправлен. Вот что говорят современные онлайн версии Оракла при выборе языка Oracle Database, либо языка Oracle PL/SQL, ошибка при этом одинаковая:
  LEFT JOIN test_4 c ON a.col_1 = c.col_1
                        *
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-00918: COL_1: column ambiguously specified - appears in TEST_3 and TEST_2

